# Finding follow sets - infinite recursion

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction

While finding follow sets, rules such as 
`A->aA` can lead to infinite recursion. Is there any coding technique to avoid it?

Note that the above example is just an example, in practice such a recursion could happen indirectly as well.

Here is my sample C code for finding follow sets. The grammar is stored as an array of linked lists. **Please tell me if the code is unclear at any point.**

```
set findFollowSet(char nonTerminal[], Grammar G, hashTable2 h)  //later assume that all first sets are already in the hashtable.
{
    LINK temp1 = find2(h, nonTerminal);     
    set s= createEmptySet();
    set temp = createEmptySet();
    char lhs[80] = "\0";
    int i;

    //special case
    if(temp1->numRightSideOf==0)     //its not on right side of any grammar rule
        return insert(s, "$");

    for(i=0;i<temp1->numRightSideOf;i++)
    {
        link l = G.rules[temp1->rightSideOf[i]];

        strcpy(lhs, l->symbol);     //storing the lhs just in case the nonTerm appears on the rightmost end of the rule.
        printf("!!!!! %s\n", lhs);
        sleep(1);
        //finding nonTerminal in G
        while(l!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(l->symbol, nonTerminal) == 0)
            break;

            l=l->next;
        }
        //found the nonTerminal in G

        if(l->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp = findFirstSet(l->next, G, h);
            temp = removeElement(temp, "EPSILON");
        }

        else    //its on the rightmost end of the rule
            temp = findFollowSet(lhs, G, h);

        s = setUnion(s, temp);  destroySet(temp);   
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: In any recursion, the first thing to do is decide upon what is your "stopping condition". With that condition, the function would stop recursing and simply returns.

Comment: @anonymous   so what would be the base case for this?

Comment: I got no idea what findFollowSet() means or what it's meant to do. I'll have to google up some info about "follow sets. Unless you can give some examples of what you're trying to do. Ahh.. Compiler Theory 101. Something that I didn't take up while in school :-). It was an elective. But I'll read it up.

Comment: Uh? are you _talking to yourself_?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez No Oscar. Two different people with same display name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIRST and FOLLOW sets are defined recursively, so you need to find the recursive closure.  What this mean in practice is that you don't find the FOLLOW set for a single non-terminal -- you find all the FOLLOW sets for all the terminals simultaneously, by starting with all sets empty and going over the grammar adding symbols to different sets, until no more symbols can be added to any set.  So you end up with something like:

```
FOLLOW[*] = {};  // all follow sets start empty
done = false;
while (!done)
    done = true;
    for (R : each rule in the grammar)
        A = RHS[R];
        tmp = FOLLOW[A];
        for (S : each symbol in LHS[R] from right to left)
            if (S is terminal)
                tmp = {S};
            else
                if (!(FOLLOW[S] contains tmp))
                    done = false
                    FOLLOW[S] |= tmp
                if (epsilon in FIRST[S])
                    tmp |= FIRST[S] - epsilon
                else
                    tmp = FIRST[S]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer but its inefficient.
So if anyone wants to suggest some more efficient answer, please feel welcomed.

Just store the recursion stack explicitly and at each recursive call, check if the entry already exists in the stack.
Mind you, you need to check the entire stack not just the top of it.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @ibid   why is it not?

Comment: It looks like a comment to some other answer, not like an answer.

Comment: @ibid   you are mistaken, its a valid answer. I coded it this way and its working  :)

Comment: Ok, it's just confusingly phrased, then. :)